# Analytic properties of power series with non-negative exponents?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the power series for complex $z$:
$$
P(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{a_n},
$$
where $a_n$ is some strictly monotonic sequence of integers starting with zero ($a_0=0$) and going to infinity as $n\to\infty$.

1. Do we know anything about the analytic properties of such generic (formal?) series? Like region of convergence (ROC), pole structure, etc? What is naively plausible is that it blows up for $z=1$, hence there must be a pole or some other type of singularity at $z=1$ and the ROC is at best the open unit disk $|z|<1$.
2. Suppose $p_i$ ($i=1,\dots,k$) are fixed positive integers and the values in the sequence $a_n$ is generated by all possible linear combinations $\sum_{i=1}^kp_in_i$, where $n_i=0,1,\dots$. That is we form this infinitely many linear combinations, keep the unique values, sort them, and that's the sequence $a_n$. Can we now say something about $P(z)$?